# sakila database staff table

Tags: mysql, sql

i am practicing using sample database 'sakila' from mysql workbench. when i try

```
select address.address,staff.address_id,store.address_id,address.address from store
join address on store.address_id=address.address_id
join staff on staff.store_id=store.store_id ;
```

i get same address in both address field irespective of different address_id.
why am i getting same adresss in both the address fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the `address` table twice with different alias name

```
select staff.address_id, a_staff.address as staff_adress,
       store.address_id, a_store.address as store_adress
from store
join staff on staff.store_id = store.store_id
join address a_staff on staff.address_id = a_staff.address_id
join address a_store on store.address_id = a_store.address_id
```

Answer (score 0):

because you join both staff and store tables with same address (actually you join address table for store table and staff table with store so address in this result set are for store not for staff) table and your join condition is only pick addresses for store not for staff and staff table joining with relevant store so why you get same address in both columns.